# Providing pointer to private member from within class

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, private

I realise that providing a method which returns a pointer to a private method breaks encapsulation, and exposes the field to anyone who uses the class. However, suppose the following:

You have a class which calls the method of another class (which expects a pointer to some private field), and the address of the private member is passed as a parameter to this method.

As far as I can see, as long as the private member's address is only exposed in a way controlled by the developer of the class, this doesn't break encapsulation (i.e. the developer knows exactly how it's going to be used). Of course, the method called could (assuming you didn't write it) expose the private member, but do we need to look that far ahead? I've seen this done countless times, so I guess it's not the result of bad design practises?

Is it bad practise to write method which take pointers to private members of other classes and modify them? Should each class only "look out for themselves"?

Comment: Answers will include subjective opinion, due to different views on whether exposing a pointer to a member "breaks encapsulation" (not exactly a precise term). If a class has a public member function that returns a pointer to private data, there is an implicit assumption the caller won't misuse it.  If the caller is untrustworthy, then it would be better not to provide such a function at all. If a member function passes the address of a member to another function, then encapsulation is maintained - encapsulation isn't about preventing deliberate actions by its own member functions.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a bad design because most classes have getters and setters to read and write to the object. So if that function needs to read and write then it should ask for object reference, not for pointer to any private memeber.

And in most of  cases when function needs a reference for variable, it asks for reference to a constant value.

Comment: What if the method needs to change the value in some way? Then wouldn't a pointer be preferable?

Comment: Can you see any cases where it would make sense for a method to receive a pointer?

Comment: In Function Oriented Programming it will make sense but in Object Oriented Programming i don't think it will make sense to receive a pointer to non-constant data. And if it's needed then you should rethink about your class design.

Comment: Does the same apply to non-const references? 
So really you'd only be using pointers in a class internally when assigning data on the heap?

Answer (score 0):

> I realise that providing a method which returns a pointer to a private method breaks encapsulation, and exposes the field to anyone who uses the class.

This is not true to begin with.

A class that has a method that returns a pointer as part of its interface is absolutely fine, and the fact that it returns a member variable is an *implementation detail* that the outside world does not need to know.

Now, that being said, it is **difficult** to design a sane class interface that involves functions that return non-owning pointers, so it's something we tend to avoid.

*Edit* as far as the second part of the question goes:

Any class is supposed to sanely handle any possible permutation of usage of its public interface (including de-referencing any returned pointers). What or who uses the public interface is supposed to be entirely irrelevant, and you should assume that all users of the class will make use of the entire public API.

If you have parts of the class that you only want to make available to specific types or functions, then that's exactly what `friend` is for. But this has nothing to do with pointers to members, it applies to any and all parts of the class.

Comment: Sure, but there's no telling how it's going to be used. And in which case it may as well be public.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the other part of the question?

Comment: @B4039 I've amended the answer.

Comment: returning a pointer to a something private is basically equivalent to making this something public. Assuming there is a good rationale for making this private in the first place, I hardly believe this can be *absolutely fine*.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Having a getter and a setter is also basically equivalent to making something public. The point of encapsulation is about disconnecting the interface from implementation, nothing else. If the interface has a pointer and it makes sense, then so be it. Now, it's hard to design a sensible interface that includes returning pointers, but this difficulty has nothing to do with breaking encapsulation.